# Set up a table for AIP Conference Proceedings

Tags: tables

I wrote this code using BaKoMa TeX (all this while, there were some errors in the process. But as long as the output comes up on the next window, I'm happy). The problem is I need to write this in `\documentclass{aip-cp}` for publication. All seems wrong. Please instruct me.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{  
\begin{tabular}{c|c|ccc|ccc}
\hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{$n$}&\multirow{2}{*}{$p$}&&$t$&&&$z$ 
\\\cline{3-8}
& & \pi/4 & \pi & 3\pi/2 & 0.35-0.55i & -0.15+0.15i & -0.25-0.35i
\\  \hline 
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1} & 3 & 9.67(-07) & 6.50(-08) & 8.18(-07) & 2.15(-07) & 1.61(-07) & 1.53(0.7)\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1} & 4 & 2.02(-06) & 5.74(-07) & 2.64(-06) & 4.99(-07) & 7.09(-07) & 1.09(-06))\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}16} & 5 & 2.59(-06) & 7.94(-07) & 7.28(-06) & 6.00(-07) & 2.97(-07) & 4.96(-07)\\\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1}& 3 & 3.27(-08) & 2.64(-09) & 4.32(-08) & 1.77(-08) & 1.05(-08) & 2.34(-08)\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1}& 4 & 3.18(-08) & 3.56(-09) & 5.77(-08) & 3.92(-08) & 3.60(08) & 6.57(-08)\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}32} & 5 & 1.67(-09) & 5.96(-10) & 3.03(-10) & 5.19(-10) & 2.56(-10) & 6.65(-10)\\ \hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1}& 3 & 2.98(-09) & 2.73(-10) & 1.89(-09) & 1.18(-09) & 7.20(-10) & 1.57(-09)\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1}& 4 & 3.36(-09) & 5.65(-11) & 6.01(-09) & 2.53(-09) & 2.22(-09) & 3.96(-09)\\
\rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}64} & 5 & 4.76(-12) & 2.97(-12) & 1.52(-12) & 3.13(-12) & 1.42(-12) & 3.18(-12)\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the output using BaKoMa and this is what I want from <code>documentstyle{aip-cp}</code>]

Comment: Why the downvote?  The question is specific and has a very good minimal example.

Comment: I believe this question got the downvote because I put the phrase "latex newbie here" at the beginning of the question (I found out from Google) - which I wasn't suppose to do that. But now I have deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all download [`aip-cp`](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors).

In the `aip-cp` documentclass, the table is no longer too wide for the text and the `\resizebox` construct can be removed (if you wanted to use it you would have needed `\usepackage{graphicx}`).

All the `\pi` need to go in dollar signs because `\pi` is only defined in math mode.

That’s already it.  Enjoy your table.

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.85}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|ccc|ccc}
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{$n$}                                         & \multirow{2}{*}{$p$} &           & $t$       &           &              & $z$
                                                                                                                                                                           \\
    \cline{3-8}
                                                                 &                      & $\pi/4$   & $\pi$     & $3\pi/2$  & $0.35-0.55i$ & $-0.15+0.15i$ & $-0.25-0.35i$ \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 3                    & 9.67(-07) & 6.50(-08) & 8.18(-07) & 2.15(-07)    & 1.61(-07)     & 1.53(0.7)     \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 4                    & 2.02(-06) & 5.74(-07) & 2.64(-06) & 4.99(-07)    & 7.09(-07)     & 1.09(-06))    \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}16} & 5                    & 2.59(-06) & 7.94(-07) & 7.28(-06) & 6.00(-07)    & 2.97(-07)     & 4.96(-07)     \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 3                    & 3.27(-08) & 2.64(-09) & 4.32(-08) & 1.77(-08)    & 1.05(-08)     & 2.34(-08)     \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 4                    & 3.18(-08) & 3.56(-09) & 5.77(-08) & 3.92(-08)    & 3.60(08)      & 6.57(-08)     \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}32} & 5                    & 1.67(-09) & 5.96(-10) & 3.03(-10) & 5.19(-10)    & 2.56(-10)     & 6.65(-10)     \\
    \hline
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.95}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 3                    & 2.98(-09) & 2.73(-10) & 1.89(-09) & 1.18(-09)    & 7.20(-10)     & 1.57(-09)     \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.85}\cellcolor[gray]{1}                     & 4                    & 3.36(-09) & 5.65(-11) & 6.01(-09) & 2.53(-09)    & 2.22(-09)     & 3.96(-09)     \\
    \rowcolor[gray]{0.75}\multirow{-4}{*}{\cellcolor[gray]{1}64} & 5                    & 4.76(-12) & 2.97(-12) & 1.52(-12) & 3.13(-12)    & 1.42(-12)     & 3.18(-12)     \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

I also created a revised version of your table with a layout I personally like.

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}C@{\qquad}C@{\qquad}CCC@{\qquad}CCC@{}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{$n$} & \multirow{2}{*}{$p$} &           & t         &           &            & z
                                                                                                                             \\
    \cmidrule(r{2em}){3-5} \cmidrule{6-8}
                         &                      & \pi/4     & \pi       & 3\pi/2    & 0.35-0.55i & -0.15+0.15i & -0.25-0.35i \\
    \midrule
                         & 3                    & 9.67(-07) & 6.50(-08) & 8.18(-07) & 2.15(-07)  & 1.61(-07)   & 1.53(0.7)   \\
    16                   & 4                    & 2.02(-06) & 5.74(-07) & 2.64(-06) & 4.99(-07)  & 7.09(-07)   & 1.09(-06)   \\
                         & 5                    & 2.59(-06) & 7.94(-07) & 7.28(-06) & 6.00(-07)  & 2.97(-07)   & 4.96(-07)   \\
    \addlinespace
                         & 3                    & 3.27(-08) & 2.64(-09) & 4.32(-08) & 1.77(-08)  & 1.05(-08)   & 2.34(-08)   \\
    32                   & 4                    & 3.18(-08) & 3.56(-09) & 5.77(-08) & 3.92(-08)  & 3.60(08)    & 6.57(-08)   \\
                         & 5                    & 1.67(-09) & 5.96(-10) & 3.03(-10) & 5.19(-10)  & 2.56(-10)   & 6.65(-10)   \\
    \addlinespace
                         & 3                    & 2.98(-09) & 2.73(-10) & 1.89(-09) & 1.18(-09)  & 7.20(-10)   & 1.57(-09)   \\
    64                   & 4                    & 3.36(-09) & 5.65(-11) & 6.01(-09) & 2.53(-09)  & 2.22(-09)   & 3.96(-09)   \\
                         & 5                    & 4.76(-12) & 2.97(-12) & 1.52(-12) & 3.13(-12)  & 1.42(-12)   & 3.18(-12)   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Henri Menke. Hope this will benefit others too.